# pam_limits.so making problems for sudo

Tags: centos, sudo, pam

I have a problem with my tomcat servers running on centos 7.
have 7 in all, set up alike. 4 have been patched recently and rebooted, remaining 3 has uptime of approx 2 years.

when I do:

```
sudo -u tomcat ls /tmp
```

I get error on the newly patched servers, stating :

```
sudo: pam_open_session: Permission denied
sudo: policy plugin failed session initialization
```

on the unpatched servers I get to execute the command.

`/etc/security/limits` are identical:

```
tomcat soft nofile 5000000
tomcat hard nofile 5000000
tomcat soft nproc  5000000
tomcat hard nproc  5000000
```

I can circumvent the errror by commenting out :

```
/etc/pam.d/sudo:

session    required     pam_limits.so
```

I dont get it ?

Am I looking in the right places ?

---

strace from both look like:

Failing:

```
strace -e setrlimit sudo -u tomcat ls /tmp
setrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
setrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=1031015, rlim_max=1031015}) = 0
setrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=5000000, rlim_max=5000000}) = 0
setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=5000000, rlim_max=5000000}) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
sudo: pam_open_session: Permission denied
sudo: policy plugin failed session initialization
+++ exited with 1 +++"
```

working:

```
strace -e setrlimit sudo -u tomcat ls /tmp
setrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=5000000, rlim_max=5000000}) = 0
setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=5000000, rlim_max=5000000}) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
setrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
hs_err_pid13726.log  hsperfdata_cron  hsperfdata_tokor  hsperfdata_tomcat  systemd-private-U8GAP7
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=28963, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

`pam` version on working is :  `pam-1.1.8-12.el7_1.1.x86_64`

and on non-working: `pam-1.1.8-18.el7.x86_64`

Comment: Further investigation has revealed that setting hard limit for tomcat user in /etc/security/limits to 1048576 will make it work ... but ???


`where does 1048576 come from ?`

`why has it changed ?`

Comment: As if pam i reverting to defaults and ignoring limits set in limits file ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug in the `pam_limits` module, causing authentication to fail.  I think it only affects RHEL/Centos 7.  It affects sudo users who have an unlimited or very high `nofiles` setting (bigger than `fs.nr_open`=1024x1024=1024576).

Your options are:

- Remove `pam_limits` from your sudo PAM rules
- Set the `nofiles` for the destination user (tomcat) to be something lower than `fs.nr_open`
- Raise the kernel setting `fs.nr_open` (in `/etc/sysctl.conf`) to be higher than your ulimit
- Wait for a fix?

Comment: how to do this when you can no longer sudo or sudo su inside the machine? any solution available in this case?

Comment: @mbrandalero If you no longer have root access at all, and there are no other users with root access, and you have lost/forgotten the root password so cannot log in via the console, then you will need to do password recovery.  Boot the system from standalone media, mount the filesystem containing /etc onto /mnt, and manually edit the password file to set a known password for root.  Then you can log in as root on the console and fix things.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the user you're running as has an expired password. I got the same error on RHEL 7 in that situation.

Comment: The update on some servers would not expire the password of any users.

Answer (score -1):

I have discovered that if `/etc/security/limits.conf` does not exist, I get the same error. If I just create an empty `/etc/security/limits.conf` file, `pam_limits`, the error disappears.

Comment: The accepted answer suggests to "remove `pam_limits` from your sudo PAM rules", which I believe would be essentially the same thing, right?

Comment: It’s not quite the same, but removing `pam_limits` from the rules would avoid errors because of a missing `limits.conf` file. Using `pam_limits` with an empty `limits.conf` is a valid configuration — files are also read from `/etc/security/limits.d/`.